# Minimize/hide Teams questions or/and Public questions on Homepage

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, homepage

When you are inside Teams, you get more than 1 question lists: one for Public SO questions, and the rest for Teams questions.

[image: SO Homepage showing questions on both Public and Teams]

I think it would be a good idea to added a little button (shown in the red circle) or some thing similar to hide/minimize one or more lists. I do not watch all day the Teams part or opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I posted this question, I have recently seen that Team Questions are removed. I believe this a solution until some thing else appear in the future or another solution comes out.

[image]

---

**UPDATE**
My observation is that when there is a new question or update to current question or answer etc. in my TEAM, it will show it for while (I think 15 days), at some point when the question/update get old and there is no longer new questions or updates, it just disappear by its own.

Answer (score -2):

I'd love to know how you managed to hide teams on your homepage - as I'm still seeing my team front and centre at that top of the my homepage.

Slightly more of an issue as I'm on the SE Moderators team, which has had confidential/sensitive information posted in the question titles, so while a corporate team is usually OK to view at work, having the Mods team visible while I'm at work with others wandering over to talk to me means I might be sharing too much ;)

Comment: Honestly, I have no clue and not done any thing, I thought it was fixed by SO, but any way my observation is that when there is a new question or update to current question or answer in my TEAM, it will show it for while (I think 15 days), at some point when the question/update get old and there is no longer new questions or updates, it just disappear by its own.

Comment: Ah - that explains it - the Mods team is clearly slightly more active then as it's permanently on top.

Comment: I have updated my anwser, in hope at some point this get more clear by SO to be more formal answer.